# How to combine color ramps for two different layers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, color-ramp

I have two layers that contains 5 polygons each with their own values. I would like to make a global color ramp that encompasses both layers. But I am not sure how I can do this. I have tried setting the number of classes under gradient colors to 10 for each layer and create my own color ramp, but ArcGIS automatically resets this back to 5 as there are only 5 values for each layer. The images below display my two layers: 0.25 degrees and 0.5 degrees.

[image]

Comment: Merge them and apply symbology from it.

Comment: ArcGIS supports multivariate (compound) symbology. It's a bit of a pain to assign patterns and colors to the combinations, by a 5x5 won't drive you crazy.

Answer (score 0):

In cartography (and graphic design in general), not only color shade can be used to represent information. See [this table](https://s1.qwant.com/thumbr/0x380/9/5/a2411fb9caff4840f939dbb33bcab558f74c930528d15b7266b1f5534f2564/Image10.gif?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww3.sympatico.ca%2Fblevis%2FImage10.gif&q=0&b=1&p=0&a=1) from the excellent [Jacques Bertin's Semiology of Graphics](https://www.esri.com/news/releases/10_4qtr/bertin.html) which lists the different visual variables and the way they should be used to represent information graphically.

For your case, you could consider representing one variable with **color shade**, and another one on top of it with a **texture** (like hatches). This can be done with ArcGIS easily.

You could also consider making a **bivariate color ramp**. See these articles, which describe more into detail the method:

- https://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/
- https://www.axismaps.com/guide/multivariate/bivariate-choropleth/
- And specifically with ArcGIS: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/mapping/mapping/making-bivariate-choropleth-maps-with-arcmap/